# Can't render a togglable component in Jest/Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm creating a Twitter clone in React; I just finished the Edit functionality/components and I'm currently trying to make test suites for it. Basically the PostFeedItem component has a state for editItem which, when true, renders the PostForm component to edit with and, when false, renders the post naturally.

Here's the PostFeedItem component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { startEditPost } from '../actions/posts';
import PostForm from './PostForm';
import moment from 'moment';

export class PostFeedItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            editItem: false
        }

        this.handleOpenEdit = this.handleOpenEdit.bind(this)
        this.handleCloseEdit = this.handleCloseEdit.bind(this)
    }

    onSubmit = (post) => {
        this.props.startEditPost(this.props.post.id, post);
        this.handleCloseEdit();
    }

    handleOpenEdit() {
        this.setState({ editItem: true })
    }

    handleCloseEdit() {
        this.setState({ editItem: false })
    }


    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                <h4>{this.props.post.user}</h4>
                <p>{moment(this.props.post.createdAt).format('MMMM Do, YYYY')}</p>
                {
                    (this.state.editItem === true) ? (
                        <div>
                            <PostForm 
                                post={this.props.post}
                                onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
                            />
                            <button onClick={this.handleCloseEdit}>Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <div>
                            <h2>{this.props.post.text}</h2>
                            <button className="edit-button" onClick={this.handleOpenEdit}>Edit Post</button>
                            <button className="remove-button">Remove Post</button>
                        </div>
                    )
                }

            </div>
        )
    }
}

// const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
//     return {
//         post: state.posts.find((post) => post.id === props.key)
//     }
// }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    startEditPost: (id, post) => dispatch(startEditPost(id, post))
})


export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(PostFeedItem);
```

This is the test I made for it so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import { PostFeedItem } from '../../components/PostFeedItem';
import posts from '../fixtures/posts';

let startEditPost, wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
    startEditPost = jest.fn();
    wrapper = mount(
        <PostFeedItem
            startEditPost={startEditPost}
            post={posts[0]}
        />
    )
})

test('should render PostFeedItem with posts', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
})

test('should toggle PostForm component', () => {
    wrapper.find('.edit-button').simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.state('editItem')).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.find('PostForm').exists()).toBeTruthy()
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();

})
```

The problem is, although clicking the edit button makes changes the state to have editItem=true, the test suite doesn't seem to be rendering the PostForm component and I get a "false" result on the test that determines if it exists. I checked the snapshot and sure enough the PostForm component isn't rendering inside of the PostFeedItem component:

```
exports[`should toggle PostForm component 1`] = `
<PostFeedItem
  post={
    Object {
      "createdAt": 0,
      "id": "1",
      "text": "This post is just a test!",
      "user": "4647ffdf",
    }
  }
  startEditPost={[Function]}
>
  <div>
    <h4>
      4647ffdf
    </h4>
    <p>
      January 1st, 1970
    </p>
    <div>
      <h2>
        This post is just a test!
      </h2>
      <button
        onClick={[Function]}
      >
        Cancel
      </button>
      <button
        className="remove-button"
      >
        Remove Post
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</PostFeedItem>
`;
```

It works fine in the actual app though. What can I do to have the test render the toggleable component properly?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! All I had to do was change the test to the following:

```
test('should toggle PostForm component', () => {
    wrapper.find('.edit-button').simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.state('editItem')).toBe(true)
    wrapper.mount();
    expect(wrapper.find('PostForm').exists()).toBeTruthy()
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();

})
```

I added the wrapper.mount() after changing the state and that updated the component just fine.

Comment: Cool :) Before checking the question itself figured it @Leopn , good :)